# Debug peewee cache hits

Tags: caching, peewee

The [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#iterating-over-large-result-sets) say:

> By default peewee will cache the rows returned when iterating over a Select query.

I would like to debug when peewee hits or misses this cache.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/628668437ef29f57d287e72d006d49908c3c5664/peewee.py), there's `row_cache` used in different places. Where should I insert a `logger` call?

I've already activated the peewee query logging. If a query is logged there, does it mean it's a cache-miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've already activated the peewee query logging. If a query is logged there, does it mean it's a cache-miss?

Yes.

The row-cache only caches rows so that multiple iterations over **the same query result** will not result in multiple executions.

Example:

```
q = User.select()
# Query is executed:
for user in q:
    print(user.email)

# Query is **not** re-executed.
for user in q:
    print(user.email)

q2 = User.select()
# Query is executed:
for user in q2:
    print(user.email)
```